video embed not scaling responsively in bootstrap 5 carousel
I have two video embeds in a carousel.
One is a standard bootstrap size (16x9), the other is a custom (4x5)
I'm using the embed-reponsive code on both, yet neither of them scale responsively to fill the container max width and height like the images do. they just stay small, always.
I've tried adding % widths on the iframe and surrounding divs, but nothing seems to work. Any ideas?
Code below (open full size to see the problem on both videos)


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Bootstrap 5 test</title>
  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  
  <style>
    body {
      background-color: lightpink;
      margin: 10px; 
      padding: 0; 
    }

  .container {
      background-color: green;
      margin-bottom: 50px;
      padding: 10px;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center; }

    }
      
  .slideshow-container {
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
      margin: auto;
      overflow: hidden;
      background-color: #b9dbe5;
      display: flex; /* Use flexbox layout */
      justify-content: center; /* Center items horizontally */
      align-items: center; /* Center items vertically */
    }
  .slideshow-container img, 
    .slideshow-container iframe {
      max-width: 100%;
     max-height: 85vh; /* Set maximum height */
    object-fit: contain;
    }
    
  .carousel-item {
      text-align: center; /* Center images horizontally */
    } 
      
 /* Custom aspect ratio for 4x5 video */
.embed-responsive-4by5::before {
  padding-bottom: 125%;
}
  </style>
</head>

<body>

<div class="container" style="max-width: 1000px;">
<div id="myCarousel1" class="slideshow-container carousel slide" data-interval="false">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/1200x800/?nature" alt="...">
      </div>
    
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/800x1200/?mountain" alt="...">
      </div>
            
            <!-- Video Slide 1-->
      <div class="carousel-item">
  <div id="nochill" class="vidbox embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9" style="max-width: 800px; margin: auto; text-align: center;">
  <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/143374377?h=760ef66606&title=0&byline=0&portrait=0" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen style="padding: 0px;"></iframe>
      </div>  
    </div>

     <!-- Video Slide 2 -->
      <div class="carousel-item">
            <div class="phonewrapper" style="max-width: 550px; margin: auto">

  <div id="phone" class="vidbox embed-responsive embed-responsive-4by5">
  <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/912417077?badge=0&amp;autopause=0&amp;player_id=0&amp;app_id=58479" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen style="padding: 0px" ></iframe>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
      
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/1000x800/?sea" alt="...">
      </div>
    </div>
  
  
    <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#myCarousel1" data-bs-slide="prev">
  <img src="images/nav-l.gif" alt="Previous" style="width: 10vh">
    </button>
    <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#myCarousel1" data-bs-slide="next">
  <img src="images/nav-r.gif" alt="Next" style="width: 10vh">
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
  


<!-- Bootstrap JS -->
<script src="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>




Please don't open the same question multiple times.

hi there, this is not the same. i rebuilt a carousel in bootstrap v5, (notv 4 as before), and many of the functions that worked before, don't seem to work now.  i've tried everything the bootstrap docs suggest that should work (including embed-responsive tags, and trying to force scaling with css on the iframes themselves, or on using surrounding divs, but nothing seems to work). any help apprecaited.

You can solve this is by using a wrapper div around the iframe and setting the padding-bottom to a percentage that represents the aspect ratio you want. This percentage is calculated as the height divided by the width times 100. For a 16:9 aspect ratio, this would be (9 / 16) * 100 = 56.25%. For a 4:5 aspect ratio, this would be (5 / 4) * 100 = 125%.
HTML:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Bootstrap 5 test</title>
  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  
  <style>
    body {
      background-color: lightpink;
      margin: 10px; 
      padding: 0; 
    }

    .container {
      background-color: green;
      margin-bottom: 50px;
      padding: 10px;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center; 
    }
      
    .slideshow-container {
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
      margin: auto;
      overflow: hidden;
      background-color: #b9dbe5;
      display: flex; /* Use flexbox layout */
      justify-content: center; /* Center items horizontally */
      align-items: center; /* Center items vertically */
    }
    .slideshow-container img, 
    .slideshow-container iframe {
      max-width: 100%;
      max-height: 85vh; /* Set maximum height */
      object-fit: contain;
    }
    
    .carousel-item {
      text-align: center; /* Center images horizontally */
    } 
      
    /* Custom aspect ratio for 4x5 video */
    .embed-responsive-4by5::before {
      padding-bottom: 125%;
    }

    .vidbox {
      position: relative;
      overflow: hidden;
      width: 100%;
      padding-bottom: 56.25%; /* for 16:9 aspect ratio */
    }

    .vidbox iframe {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }

    .embed-responsive-4by5 .vidbox {
      padding-bottom: 125%; /* for 4:5 aspect ratio */
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

<div class="container" style="max-width: 1000px;">
<div id="myCarousel1" class="slideshow-container carousel slide" data-interval="false">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/1200x800/?nature" alt="...">
      </div>
    
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/800x1200/?mountain" alt="...">
      </div>
            
            <!-- Video Slide 1-->
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <div id="nochill" class="vidbox embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
          <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/143374377?h=760ef66606&title=0&byline=0&portrait=0" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>  
      </div>

     <!-- Video Slide 2 -->
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <div class="phonewrapper embed-responsive embed-responsive-4by5">
          <div id="phone" class="vidbox">
            <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/912417077?badge=0&autopause=0&player_id=0&app_id=58479" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/1000x800/?sea" alt="...">
      </div>
    </div>
  
  
    <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#myCarousel1" data-bs-slide="prev">
      <img src="images/nav-l.gif" alt="Previous" style="width: 10vh">
    </button>
    <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#myCarousel1" data-bs-slide="next">
      <img src="images/nav-r.gif" alt="Next" style="width: 10vh">
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
  


<!-- Bootstrap JS -->
<script src="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>

This should make iframes take up the full width and height of their parent divs, and the videos will scale up or down while maintaining their aspect ratios.
